# What is the most optimal data structure for storing a partially-ordered set (poset)?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, set, time-complexity, poset

I am looking for a data structure for storing a poset, that supports the following operations with good big-Oh complexity (these are done frequently):

- determining if a given element can be consistently ordered before another one (top priority above others)
- adding new ordering constraints
- returning all elements that can be ordered before a given element

The data structure must also support generating a totally ordered set from the poset, but that only needs to be done once for the output after the algorithm has already run.

So far I have been relying on a naive poset implementation, but I am reaching a point where that is no longer sustainable.

I have looked at https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/what-persistent-data-structure-for-a-set-of-partially-ordered-elements, and there are some interesting papers in the answers, but most of these data structures (like `ChainMerge`) seem to be optimized with sorting in mind, where for me it is the least important step.

Comment: If you maintain the transitive closure -- i.e., a graph in which there is an edge x->y exactly when x > y -- then testing whether it's possible to add a new edge x->y is constant time (if you use an adjacency matrix (O(|V|^2) space) or adjacency list representation in which each vertex stores a hashtable of all vertices that it precedes): all you have to do is check for the absence of a reverse edge y->x. Updating this data structure when the edge is added is slow, however: worst case O(|V|).